# How can I assign treatment and control group based on a particular variable?

Tags: r

I have two variables, `X1` and `X2`, and I use the logit function (`e^x/(1+e^x)`) to transform these two variables to a third variable `X3`. So, `X3` is a variable that ranges from 0 to 1. Based on the probabilities, I want to assign a dummy variable 1 and 0 to each individuals. There is only one rule for this assignment, the higher the probability, the higher chance to be assigned in the treatment group.

Comment: Hi Jacky, I flagged this question as belonging on http://stats.stackexchange.com/ as this question isn't really about R programming.

Comment: I am assuming your data set name is df, So: 
`df$dummy <- ifelse(df$X3 >= 0.5, 1, 0)`
The threshold value in this instance is 0.5
You can fiddle around with this

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign the two groups based on a fixed threshold, then you can use the suggestion by @dimitris_ps. In this case, the threshold is 50%.

```
ifelse(df$X3 >= 0.5, "Treatment", "Control")
```

If you want to assign the two groups randomly, then you can generate random numbers between 0 and 1, and then assign the individual to `Treatment` if the random number is below the random number. `runif(n)` generates `n` random numbers between 0 and 1.

```
set.seed(1) # So you get the same random numbers each time you run it.
ifelse(df$X3 <= runif(n), "Treatment", "Control")
```